# adding carousel items using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on an inserting form that inserts a product to a **[ products draft ]** so I have two tables 
one called **( Drafts )** and the other is **( items )** each item in the last table (items) have a draft id.

When inserting a new Draft it supposes that the client who is adding the draft have entered the number of the products in the draft so when he entered the number of the products the application well call a number of forms to insert each one of them **( the determined number of products )** so I used jquery to insert the product forms inside a bootstrap 4 carousel as a **( carousel-item )** using (append) and within each form, there is a navbar ( shows which form is this ) like this ( 1 / 50 ) and my question is which element (DOM) I have to append my code to I tried this:- and nothing happens

Code Snippet:-

```html
<?
include("..\include\basket-module.php");
// notifications //
include("..\\include\\notif-module.php");
// module //
include("..\\include\\Insert-module.php");
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Project - new Draft</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="ScreenOrientation" content="autoRotate:disabled">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap4 Library and Font-awesome with Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\profile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\newdraft.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\newproduct.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\Styles\navegationbar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap4 Library and Font-awesome with Custom CSS End-->
    <!-- including custom javascript -->
    <script src="..\js\functions\js.js"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction(event){ // **** PS: I Think the problem is with the carousel-item status ( $actives )
    var formscount = $('#count').val();
    if (formscount > 0) {
        for (i=0; i < formscount; i++) {
            $('#demo').append($('<div class="carousel-item '+<?=$actives;?>+'"><center><nav class="navbar counter justify-content-center" style="width:70vh; background-color:#86377b;"><a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family:tahoma; font-size:28px; text-shadow:4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1); color:white;">'+i+'</a></nav></center></div>'));
            event.preventDefault()
        }
    }
}
    </script>
    <!-- Fontawseome Kit -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d75f59893e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts  -->
    <!-- Bootstrap Jquery JavaScripts Ends -->
    <!-- navegtion bar bootstrap 4  -->
    <?php include("..\\home\\navbar.php"); ?>
    <!-- basket sidebar -->
    <?php include("..\\home\\basket.php"); ?>
    <!-- Main Products Form -->
    <center>
        <div class="card justify-content-center cont">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-text">
                    <nav class="navbar header justify-content-center">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-family:hana; font-size:28px; text-shadow:4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,1); color:white;">إدخال المنتجات</a>
                    </nav>
                    <hr />
                    <center>
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                        <input name="count" id="count" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="عدد النماذج">
                        <button onclick="myFunction(event)">إضافة النماذج</button>
                        </form>
                        <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="height:50vh;">

                            <!-- Indicators -->
                            <ul class="carousel-indicators" style="background-color: black; color:black;">
                                <?
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach($result as $row){
                                    $actives = '';
                                if($i == 0){
                                    $actives ='active';
                                }
                                ?>
                                <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="<?= $i; ?>" class="<?= $actives; ?>"></li>
                                <? $i++ ; }?>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- The slideshow -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner canner">
                            <div class="carousel-item"><img src="<?= $row['imageurl']?>" Height=75% alt="inner"></div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Left and right controls -->
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Update:- a new problem pops up is when I append a new ( carouesl-items ) nothing happens it just showing one active items even the indicator is a one 
updated the snippet to see the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run this in the console it says that `current(i)` is not defined, so if you remove it and leave just second occurrence of `i` instead you'll get this result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what about adding a carousel-item? where I can append the code? because when I append it in ($demo) nothing shows